# How to programmatically read a PassKit Pass's thumbnail

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a companion app which is interacting with a PassKit PKPass object. I'm trying to read the the thumbnail image (not the icon) which is part of the pass but can't find an API to call. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this doesn't look like it's possible. I solved this by base64 encoding the image and putting it in the userInfo part of the JSON body. Sucks to have to effectively include the image twice.